# How to set the fill color of the cell when it is dynamically created? TCPDF

Tags: php, tcpdf

How can I set fill parameter to a certain row and col? Anyhelp?
$fill is the variable I used, any ideas?

```
$row = 10;
$col = 10;
$w = 8;
$h = 8;

for ($r=1;$r<=$row;$r++) 
{
   for ($c=1;$c<=$col;$c++) 
   {
      $pdf->Cell($w,$h, 'STRING' ,1,0,'C',$fill);               
   }
   $pdf->Ln();
}
```

Comment: Please clean your code!

Answer (score 3):

You cand do it using your row count and module operation like:

```
$row = 10;
$col = 10;
$w =8;
$h=8;

for ($r=1;$r<=$row;$r++) 
 {
  if($r%2==0) { //here you can change your logic
   $fill = "#F0F0F0";
  } else {
   $fill = "#FFFFFF";
  }
  for ($c=1;$c<=$col;$c++) 
  {
   $pdf->Cell($w,$h, 'STRING' ,1,0,'C',$fill); 
  }
 $pdf->Ln();
}
```